Have you ever noticed that in numpad "/" and "*" keys are really close?
I had to empty a folder in linux fs with this command as administrator.
sudo rm -R *

I used the numpad to type "*" and for mistake I typed "/" that is really close, then the result was:
sudo rm -R /

The rhetorical question is: how can I recover a linux machine?

This rhetorical question is a problem you actually face?

Yes... it's a very big issue when you replace * with / in my command.

There are many potential duplicates to this question https://www.google.com/search?q=linux%20recovery%20deleted%20site%3Asuperuser.com

@Tobia - If you actually face this problem then it's not a rhetorical question. I don't make a habit of answering rhetorical questions.

the title question does not match the question in the post ... please correct one of them

Don't take too seriusly this question. I just wanted to share a misadventure
